# Mule JDBC update works intermittently

Tags: jdbc, driver, mule, esb

I need to constantly update a table in a loop and it works fine most of the times but once in a while Mule does update the table but it is not committed.

So, here is my flow.  I poll a table where the flag is 0.  Once it is polled, flag is set to 5.  After calling a service, flag is set to 1.  But if the service call fails, the flag is set back to 0 so that it'll be re-polled and processed.

If the service is down for few minutes, then this loop should keep going till the service is up.  The below statement works mostly fine, but sometimes it doesn't update and the loop is broken.

Not sure whether it is Mule or DriverManager issue.

```
<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint queryTimeout="-1"  queryKey="updateEventReset" connector-ref="DatabaseEvents" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="Database"/>
```

Flow:

```
<mule>
<spring:bean id="jdbcEASDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
</spring:bean>
<jdbc-ee:connector dataSource-ref="jdbcEASDataSource" name="DatabaseEvents" transactionPerMessage="true" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="10000" doc:name="Database">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
    <jdbc-ee:query key="selectEvent" value="select * from EVENT_TEST where PROCESSED = 0 ORDER BY RowId" />
    <jdbc-ee:query key="selectEvent.ack" value="update EVENT_TEST set PROCESSED = 5 where RowId = #[map-payload:ROWID]" />
    <jdbc-ee:query key="updateEventProcessed" value="update EVENT_TEST set PROCESSED = 1 where RowId = #[flowVars['RowId']]" />
    <jdbc-ee:query key="updateEventReset" value="update EVENT_TEST set PROCESSED = 0 where PROCESSED = 5" />
</jdbc-ee:connector>
<flow name="EventLinkerDBPolling" doc:name="EventLinkerDBPolling" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint queryKey="selectEvent" connector-ref="ISeriesDatabaseEvents" doc:name="ACSC Database"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="vm.toEventWSCall" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="To Event Dining" />
</flow>
<flow name="EventWSProcessing" doc:name="EventWSProcessing" processingStrategy="synchronous">
      <vm:inbound-endpoint path="vm.toEventWSCall" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="Event " >
        <vm:transaction action="NONE"/>
      </vm:inbound-endpoint>
      <set-variable variableName="RowId" value="#[map-payload:ROWID]" doc:name="Variable"/>
  <flow-ref name="ManagerClient" doc:name="Call  Flow Linker" />
      <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint queryKey="updateEventProcessed" connector-ref="DatabaseEvents" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="Database"/>
  <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[ payload.getStatusCode() == 404 ]">
        <processor-chain>
            <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint queryTimeout="-1"  queryKey="updateEventReset" connector-ref="DatabaseEvents" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="Database"/>
        </processor-chain>
        </when>
    </choice> 
  </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Do you see any Exception or Error in the log?

Comment: No, i see the below lines in the log. It updates the rows but not committing. com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sql.command.executor.PreparedSqlCommandExecutor: Command executed successfully: update EVENT_TEST set PROCESSED = 0 where PROCESSED = 5
com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.UpdateSqlStatementStrategy: Executing SQL statement: 0 row(s) updated

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the issue turned out to be an internal Mule exception.
https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6889

I can't see the foreach loop in your flow. How are you looping?
This exception is quite specific to for each loops. By restructuring the flow I could relatively easy sort it out (after weeks of troubleshooting)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  Sorry, due to incorrect format, my question didn't have whole ESB flow, i fixed it now.  In the flow, i'm calling another WebService and if the call fails i set the "Processed" flag back to 0, so that this DB row will get picked up in the next DB polling.  This is how i'm making the loop.

Comment: I also did not see the exception on the first shot, the exception could be somewhere else in the Mule-flow. It is not necessarily throwing the exception when submitting the commit.

Comment: Btw: The statement you posted says: Executing SQL statement: 0 row(s) updated - which is already the commit message from my point of view. So basically the Update just had no effect. That seems more like a problem with the SQL statement that you write. Maybe a wrong where parameter.... Also obviously it could be a timing issue. When doing WebService calls in parallel it could be that it receives the calls in a different order then sending them.